# Why does MySQL replication break on missing row, then continue after "START SLAVE"?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-replication, master-slave, slave

The title is a bit confusing, but I can't think of a better one.

What I have is a simple vanilla MySQL replication, with the slave occasionally failing, with this error: `Error 'Can't find record in 'my_tbl'' on query. Default database: 'my_db'. Query: 'UPDATE my_tbl SET ...  WHERE ...'` (columns omitted for clarity).

What I'm assuming this error means, is that the slave sql thread executed this update, and received `0 rows affected`. This was not what it expected when comparing the result of `1 rows affected` from the relay log, thus generating an error.

When running this same update transaction manually, it works. Same thing when running `START SLAVE` - it just starts working, and goes back to normal.

This doesn't make sense to me at all - if all it takes is a "retry" to fix this, how could this happen in the first place? Everything is executed in a serialized fashion, and nothing else is writing to the slave mysql server.

Can someone provide an explanation?

Some technicalities - this is a mixed replication setup from 5.5.7-rc to 5.5.12.

Answer (score 2):

There is a filed [MySQL bug #60091](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60091) regarding the replication of InnoDB tables that may meet your conditions - take a look at it, check if your version is affected and update it eventually to check if it helps matters.

Another explanation for this would be out-of-order execution - when the `UPDATE my_tbl SET ... WHERE ...` is run, the WHERE condition can not yet be met by any row since it has still to happen. I can't think of a reason for that though - this would be something to ask about on MySQL mailing lists.

Comment: Out of order execution would fit, but it doesn't make sense since it's a slave - and the only changes are made by the slave sql thread. What else could I check?

Comment: Also, the bug in question is fixed in 5.5.12, which is the version I'm running. Also, the table in question has a PK.

Comment: Hm, are you using some non-deterministic functions in your WHERE clause by any chance? And are you mixing MyISAM and InnoDB tables in your database?

Comment: Neither... Regular key lookup, and only InnoDB tables (single table is accessed in the query)

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the reason behind this problem - an event which was running on the master and on the slave as well.
The solution is simple - `alter event event_name disable on slave;` Something to keep in mind when creating a slave with `mysqldump`.